# Date Validation using ASP.NET MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've Date field on my MVC UI named "startDate", the user selects date using jquery date picker. As i wanted to validate that selected date should not be 2 months past and 2 months future.

I've wrote the below code for validating the date.

```
 public sealed class DateAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EmailAddressAttribute"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public DateAttribute() : base(DataType.Date)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks that the value of the data field is valid.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The data field value to validate.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// true always.
        /// </returns>
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime inputDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

            if (inputDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-2) && inputDate.Date <= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(2))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

But the issue is, it goes to server for validating the date field. how can i achive same with client validation.

Thanks,
-Naren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function IsValid(object) {  
    var theDate = new Date(object);  
    var pointfrom = (theDate.getFullYear() * 100) + (theDate.getMonth());  
    var today = new Date();  
    if (pointfrom > (today.getFullYear() * 100) + (today.getMonth()) + 2) return false;  
    if (pointfrom < (today.getFullYear() * 100) + (today.getMonth()) - 2) return false;  
    return true;  
 }
```

I factor the year up by 100, thereby avoiding cross year comparison

Then on your SPAN id="x" onBlur="IsValid(this.value)">2001-01-01

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Is limiting the available dates on the datepicker sufficient?

With jquery ui's datepicker this is pretty easy with the minDate and maxDate options, most others have similar functionality.

Comment: Validation really needs to be done server-side too, as it can easily be bypassed at the client-side.

Comment: Thanks Paul, we can restrict the calendar dates, but user can enter date whcih is of out of date range.

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried using the standard [Range validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx) in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attribute instead? Something like:

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), 
    DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-2).ToShortDateString(), 
    DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(2).ToShortDateString(), 
    ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

Worth a try!

Comment: I'm happy for this to be downvoted as it clearly doesn't work (I hadn't tried it). I was going to delete, but better to leave as an example so people can learn that you can't use variables in attribute params.