# Compare dateTime and string in the datavalidationattribute of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model which consists of Employee basic details. Among the details there is a field named `Date of Birth`. The property with data annotations on it is given below:

```
[RegularExpression("(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20[0-9][0-9]", ErrorMessage = "Date should be in dd/mm/yyyy format")]
public string DateOfBirth
{
    get; set;
}
```

The date of Birth should have two validations condition:-

1. It should be in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.
2. `Date of Birth` should be less than today's date.

For the first condition I have applied a regular expression as you can see above.

I want a solution for the 2nd validation condition. Since `Data of Birth` is in `String` format how can it compare with a `DateTime` format? Is there any solution?

Comment: Why are you storing the `DateOfBirth` as a `string`?

Comment: because Regex only parse string not DateTime and Regex is the best way to check the format of Date.

Comment: I think you're mixing up the concept of how you display data vs. how it's stored. Consider the `DateTime` data type. If you issue `Convert.ToDateTime` against `30/08/2012` and `8/30/2012` it will create the same `DateTime` value. In contrast, if I have a `DateTime` value that is `8/30/2012`, I can display it ***numerous*** ways (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud is correct. Once it's DateTime, it's easy to get server side validation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250821/date-validation-using-asp-net-mvc-3-0